# DataBase Design(Big Table)

Tags: mysql

What is big table(i.e Google DataBase design), I have such type of requirement, but I don't know how to design it.

In Big Table, how to maintain relations among them?

Answer (score 0):

create all table with innodb storage engine which maintain relationships

Choose table fields according to and limited to requirement

Answer (score -1):

The paper of Big table, published by google, may be hard to read. Hope my answer can help you to start understanding.

In old days, RDBMS stores data according rows, one record one row, 1,2,3,4,5.....

Then if you want to find record 5, it's ok, database will seek in a B+ tree(or something similar) to get the address of record 5, load it for you.

But the nightmare is when you want to get records that have column "user=Michael", the database has no way but seek every record to check out if the user is "Michael".

Big Table has a different way to store data. It stores all the columns by an inverted table. When we want to find out all the records that satisfy "user=Michael", it seeks this as a key via a B+ tree or hash table, and gets the address of inverted table where stores the list of all records satisfying.

Maybe a good starting point is Lucene, an open source full text search engine,  a fully implementation of big table principles.

Be noticed, inverted table is not a column-based storage in RDBMS. They are different, please must remember this.